# Could we curve the flight path of a photon?

Tags: photons

I was wondering about photon's interaction with matter, and why photons dont slow down. They seem to always bounce in a straight line at the same speed (I think), as if some force is charging them forward after the bounce. First, what is this? I've heard of experiments where we actually did slow them down, and they can be absorbed and bounced by matter, so I wanted to know if they interact with matter in such a way that we could spin one, like a curve ball thrown by a pitcher, and make them curve their flight path.

Can someone explain this, in English (back it up by math if you need to but I'm not a physicist, I just like to learn about the fundamental ideas)?

Comment: Photons don't move, at all. They are simply quanta of the electromagnetic field and they only exist where you measure them/where an actual interaction occurs. It's the field that "moves". How the field "moves" is very well known. In the classical limit it's given by Maxwell's equations and in the quantum limit we have the equations of quantum electrodynamics, which, of course, can couple to charged matter.

Comment: @CuriousOne Hmm, so if you measure the same one in two different places doesn't that mean it has moved?

Comment: @Viziionary There is no way to even know, the two photons you measured are the same ones, as photons are not individuals but indistinguishable quanta. Being the same is just not a question you can ask about photons (just as you cannot ask whether two units of currency on your bank account are the same).

Comment: You can't write "Kilroy was here!" on a photon (that is really a quantum state, rather than a particle), so you can't distinguish "them". The entire mental model of little hard balls flying trough the universe is 100% wrong.

Comment: @SebastianRiese but couldn't I measure the same location again and check whether the photon is still there? If there is one at one instant, and then at that very precise very small location, in the next very small fraction of a nano second, if there are no photons filling that point of space, can't we assume that photons do move?

Comment: @CuriousOne or more simply, can't we prove that they move merely by the fact that a solar panel absorbs light, meaning the photons *have* to be moving in order to collide with the panel? I'm not trying to be difficult, only to understand. The idea that photons don't move just seems to make no sense.

Comment: You can measure all you want, but none of these measurements will differentiate between "Joe, the photon" and "Jane, the photon". Measuring a photon is the same as saying "We found a hydrogen atom in an s-state". In the self-consistent description of QFT photons are not particles but quanta and quanta are neither individualized nor are they moving. They are discrete (not discretized!) exchange quantities between fields. That has been known since 1900, when Planck needed them for the explanation of the black body spectrum.

Comment: @CuriousOne my point is that since there isnt a photon is every single point in space at every single instant in time, we could certainly measure a space where a photon is, and then where one isn't, and then regardless of whether or not we can identify the photon, we can prove that **a** photon was here, and now there isn't one here, so the little guys must be moving. That would seem to be rock solid proof that they move.

Comment: Unless you measure them, there are no photons, at all. The field propagation is a perfectly "smooth" dynamic phenomenon. Photons only "happen" when you make the electromagnetic field interact with matter in such a way that you produce a long term record of that interaction. You are basically in need of a beginners class in quantum mechanics where this is being discussed in detail. At the moment, do yourself a favor and simply stop thinking about photons as particles. They are clicks in a detector or black spots on a photographic plate and that is all they ever will be.

Comment: @CuriousOne so in other words, photons are imaginary...

Comment: No, photons are not imaginary. They are very real, they are simply not hard balls that fly trough the universe.

Comment: Photons are also what is emitted when an atom jumps to a lower energy state.... And one can say that the photon was emitted at an atom in point A and later detected at point B.

Comment: It is possible to make light follow any trajectory you want. You just need to put it inside an optical fiber and you can bend the fiber into your favorite shape.

Comment: It may be a better question to ask if light can curve and the answer is yes. But I am sure this question alteady exists on the Physics StackExchange.

Comment: Photons don't bounce. They are absorbed and then re-emitted as a new photon. The path of the photon can be deflected by gravity.  I would agree with many others that photons do move and travel from One point to another. And of course they're not hard balls. Most light  phenomena can be explained with particles.

Comment: I can feel some ideology in some of the remarks above. You could have only one photon (i.e. quanta) emitted, and consider how this field propagate (since it does propagate).  Just setting "photons don't move" and similar claims can easily cause  more misunderstandings replacing the misunderstanding you aimed at, which is countraproductive. And it the question is about the propagating speed of something, the very name of the something is not necessarily the true heart of the question.

Comment: So many questionable comments here. This should be moved to chat as it does not concern the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

The lenses in my reading glasses bend the path of photons, as does gravity. In matter photons move at slower speed than $c$. In Bose-Einstein condensates they can even be brought to a halt.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Anna's response,

In small scales, photons wont slow down because they are thought of as being relativisitc quantum fields in all their possible interaction channels. However, at large scales (cosmological distances) there is an indication of slowness (delay in arrival time)-- either due to a varying gravitational potential (due to non-flat spacetime fabric as mentioned by Anna) or due to the expansion of Universe itself.

Einstein himself argued that in the absence of gravity and expansion of Universe (which he was reluctant to believe in the latter) light would never slow down or speed up and was able to show it explicitly.But, current frontier research at *small-scale*, *everyday life* and *large scale* are positive after all that they are seeing a varying speed of light. (Related sources: [Varying Speed of Light](https://inspirehep.net/search?ln=en&ln=en&p=find%20t%20varying%20speed%20of%20light&of=hb&action_search=Search&sf=earliestdate&so=d&rm=&rg=25&sc=0))

Comment: Yes that is correct. The only thing that distinguishes individual particles is the Pauli exclusion principle so they are only distinguishable by their individual quantum states.

Comment: Just because photons are not indistinguishable does not mean they're not individual. Besides how does this answer the ops question?

Comment: Downvote was because you're misunderstanding the way this site is supposed to work. You aren't supposed to present a request for challenge or debate, you need to present your answer purely as a detailed explanation of the answer to the question asked.

Comment: Dear Jaywalker, Yes any measurement can tell us which one is up and which one is down. But no experiment can tell us which one was No. 1 and which one was No.2 This was meant as indistinguishibility of the particles which is also true for photon. And, apologized for mistaking a comment with an answer. Should have been more careful in submitting it. So, I will be editing my response to better reflect the answer being asked.

Answer (score 0):

> so I wanted to know if they interact with matter in such a way that we could spin one, like a curve ball thrown by a pitcher, and make them curve their flight path.

Photons interact with matter with the electromagnetic interaction. There can be [elastic scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_scattering) of a photon of energy E with a charged particle and only the angle will change , but it happens at one point in space and time , not a continuous curve.

So individual photons do not act like a classical ball, which should be expected as they are quantum mechanical entities.

Light , which is composed out of an innumerable number of photons  does display a "curve" in space collectively in a lattice, by additions of the behavior of the collective photon ensemble, as in [optical fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_fiber).

There also exists [gravitational lensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) of light :

> A gravitational lens refers to a distribution of matter (such as a cluster of galaxies) between a distant source and an observer, that is capable of bending the light from the source, as it travels towards the observer.

Individual photons are elastically scattering but the light wave displays curvature.